# REGEXP_SUBSTR usage

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

I have a Snowflake table with a column containing the values [6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]. I need to create three new columns, col1 with a value of 6326.72, col2 with a value of -548.99, and col3 with a value of -80.29 using a SELECT statement.

I tried using the regular expression `-?\d+\.+\d+` to achieve this, but for some reason, it is not returning the correct result. Can anyone advise on this requirement of using a regular expression with Snowflake REGEXP_SUBSTR?

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '-?\d+\.+\d+', 1, 1) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '-?\d+\.+\d+', 1, 2) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '-?\d+\.+\d+', 1, 3) AS col3;
```

Thank you!

Comment: "it is not returning the correct result" - what error / result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need REGECP for this. This should give the result you expected:

```
SELECT split( trim( '[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]' , '[]' )  ,',') x,
 x[0]::varchar col1,
 x[1]::varchar col2,
 x[2]::varchar col3;

+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------+
|                     X                      |  COL1   |   COL2   |  COL3   |
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------+
| [   "6326.72",   " -548.99",   " -80.29" ] | 6326.72 |  -548.99 |  -80.29 |
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

SPLIT: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split

TRIM: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim

Anyway, here is the REGEXP version:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '([^\\[\\], ]+)', 1, 1) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '([^\\[\\], ]+)', 1, 2) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('[6326.72, -548.99, -80.29]', '([^\\[\\], ]+)', 1, 3) AS col3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gokhan;  appreciate the quick fix.  fan of you ever since Oracle days :)

Comment: You are welcome. I know SO doesn't like any personal communication but it would be rude to ignore such a kind comment!

Answer (score 1):

A variation using `regexp_substr_all`

```
select '[3456.7288, -23425.9999, -234234.29]' as num_string,
       regexp_substr_all(num_string,'[0-9.-]+') as num_array,
       num_array[0]::varchar as num1, --cast to appropriate data type as desired
       num_array[1]::varchar as num2,
       num_array[2]::varchar as num3
```